# How to set up a backend API system using sql views?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, architecture, backend

I am making a large scale API for a platform. And I am designing the backend API. There will be a large SQL database. Now the problem is how to design the API logic to be very flexible and maintainable long term. From what I know there are two approaches I can take

Option 1

- database layer (i.e. mysql)
- abstraction layer 1 (has an endpoint for each table in the database, and just returns the table)
- abstraction layer 2 (has an endpoint for all relevant queries a client could want such as getting all invoices "/api/orders". each endpoint queries the previous abstraction for each desired table, joins them and returns result to the client)

Option 2

- database layer (i.e. mysql) (contains views for many things)
- abstraction layer (which has en endpoint for every relevant query a user could want which is mapped to views in the database layer)

Can anyone explain the pros and cons of each method and which to generally use?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two different questions here:

1. Should I use views?
2. Should I have multiple abstraction layers?

The answer to #1 is (as in most questions) "it depends".  Views are great ways of simplifying your database for a given use-case.  You can denormalize your data and generally simply your model.  You should *not* create them for every table as a matter-of-course, just use them when you need to simplify that model for consumption.  Be aware that you will have to be very careful in their design if you want them to be writeable.

#2 Having multiple abstraction layers can be helpful if you have a particularly complex domain.  I would not add it just to encapsulate the database tables, simply because that doesn't hide any complexity, it just changes where the work is done.  Moving that out of the database and into application space has all the complexity of the database + all the latency of application-layer.  Let the database do what it does well.  However, if there are some particularly gnarly table structures, it can benefit from another abstraction layer.  This would effectively be building a "model" layer to separate out the model from the API layer.